# Vue.js: "onSuccess" and "onFailure" callbacks not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amazon-cognito

I am implementing *Login with Facebook* using *amazon-cognito-auth-js* in Vue.js. I am using the following component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="signup">      
      <button @click="signUpFacebook">Sign in with Facebook</button>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
  import * as AmazonCognitoIdentity from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
  import {CognitoAuth} from 'amazon-cognito-auth-js';
  var cognitoUserPoolId = 'xxxx'; 
  var cognitoUserPoolClientId = 'xxx'; 
  var appclient_id  = 'xxxx'

  export default {
    name: 'signup',
    data(){
      return {
        email_address: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPw: '',
        auth: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      signUpFacebook : function(){
        this.auth.getSession();
      }
    },
    created() {

          var authData = {
            ClientId : appclient_id, // Your client id here
            AppWebDomain : 'my-sample-app.amazoncognito.com',
            TokenScopesArray : ['email'], 
            RedirectUriSignIn : 'http://localhost:8080',
            RedirectUriSignOut : 'http://localhost:8080',
            IdentityProvider : 'Facebook', // e.g. 'Facebook',
            UserPoolId : cognitoUserPoolId, // Your user pool id here
          };

          this.auth = new CognitoAuth(authData)
          console.log(this.auth)

          this.auth.userhandler = {
            // * E.g.
            onSuccess: function(result) {
              alert("Sign in success");
              showSignedIn(result);
            },
            onFailure: function(err) {
              alert("Error!" + err);
            }          
          }

          console.log("authdata set")

          var redirect_url = window.location.href;
          this.auth.parseCognitoWebResponse(redirect_url);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Although the user is redirected and authenticated, the "onSuccess", "onFailure" callbacks are never called. Is there something I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, I found the **onSuccess** callback worked when I changed *RedirectUriSignIn* in *authData* as follows:

```js
var authData = {
   ClientId : appclient_id, // Your client id here
   AppWebDomain : 'my-sample-app.amazoncognito.com',
   TokenScopesArray : ['email'], 
   RedirectUriSignIn : 'http://localhost:8080/signup',  <------- here
   RedirectUriSignOut : 'http://localhost:8080',
   IdentityProvider : 'Facebook', // e.g. 'Facebook',
   UserPoolId : cognitoUserPoolId, // Your user pool id here
};
```

This will redirect to the component where *amazon-cognito-auth-js* is initialized.

In my case, I was redirecting it to the **'/'** *(Home.vue)*, which didn't have *amazon-cognito-auth-js* initialized, everything was initialized in **'/signup'** *(SignUp.vue)* so it makes sense to redirect to the '/signup' route.

Make sure to change the redirect_url as well, in AWS Cognito App client settings:

```sh
AWS Console --> Cognito --> Userpools --> App client settings --> Sign in and sign out URLs --> Callback URL(s)
```

Change  Callback URL(s) to:

```
http://localhost:8080/signup
```